# Difference between MAMP and DigitalOcean LAMP Ubuntu 14.04 server messing up Joomla Custom Form Field

Tags: php, ubuntu, joomla, joomla2.5, php-ini

I wrote a Custom Form Field on a Joomla 2.5 site.

My form field selects an id value and tag name from a database table, and allows you to select multiple checkboxes.  Pretty simple.

My problem is that the code works perfectly on my dev server (MAMP, standard settings), but doesn't work on my DigitalOcean Ubuntu 14.04 VPS.

[image: MAMP]

MAMP (above)

VS

DigitalOcean (below)

[image: Digital Ocean]

So yeah, I'm looking for ideas here.  My main thought is that it's in the PHP Settings, in Disabled Functions.

MAMP has no disabled functions, Digital Ocean has the following:

Disabled Functions  pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I commented out the disabled functions for a moment, restarted the server.  Got some different console errors which was interesting, but it didn't fix the problem.  Any other suggestions?

UPDATE 2:  Solved by changing filename to all lowercase on production server.  Answer below shows detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when Joomla doesn't find the custom form field definition — in those cases it reverts to a standard text `input` element.

Depending on how you moved the site from your MAMP setup to the live Ubuntu VPS you may have missing files.

If you followed the Joomla standard for custom form fields you should have something like this:

`/components/com_mycomponent/models/fields/mycomponentmultitags.php`

I would check that your custom field file exists on the VPS and that it's permissions are set correctly (644 should do it).

#### Update

In respect to the cause of the problem (i.e. filename case). So file systems are case sensitive and some aren't, and some are case aware (i.e. show the case) but not case sensitive. I should've picked up you were on MAMP (ie. a Mac), OSX runs on HFS+. HFS+ is, by default, not case sensitive but is case preserving. So calling the all lowercase name of the file will work on MAMP but not on Ubuntu (because *it* **is case sensitive**.

Which in this case tak you back to the fact that Joomla (aka PHP) couldn't find the custom form field definition (aka the file `CategoryCheckBoxes.php` because it was looking for `categorycheckboxes.php`)

Comment: Hey thank you for your response!

Already had permissions set to 644 (chown'd to www-data and all).

Mine is actually in admin
administrator/components/com_componentname/models/fields/CategoryCheckBoxes.php

with JFormFieldCategoryCheckBoxes extending JFormField inside

every file I modified is synced.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I got it to work, but I don't like not knowing why it worked.

Again, it worked on development (MAMP) but not on my Production VPS (Standard Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP Apache2)

I changed:

administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/fields/CategoryCheckBoxes.php

to:

administrator/components/com_mycomponent/models/fields/categorycheckboxes.php

Yes, I made the filename all lowercase and it worked like a charm.  That's all I changed.  Does anyone know why that would happen and why it would differ on the server type?

Comment: Yes - see my updated answer, (my bad for ignoring the MAMP reference in your question).